# Exclude null values using DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, dense-rank

Dense_Rank is taking everything into account. Is there a way to exclude the null values so the next rank after 1 would be 2 and not 3.

This is what the table looks like now:

```
 A     | DENSE_R 
 --------------
 1     | 1  
 --------------
 2     | null  
 --------------
 3     | 3 
 --------------
 4     |  4
```

This is what I want the table to look like:

```
 A     | DENSE_R 
 --------------
 1     | 1  
 --------------
 2     | null  
 --------------
 3     | 2 
 --------------
 4     |  3
```

I'm using the following code to do so:-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT A 
 FROM A1
)
SELECT A,
CASE 
  WHEN  **Condition**
  THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order by [A] ASC)
END
AS 'DENSE_R'
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `partition by` the same `**Condition**` as you used already.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT A 
 FROM A1
)
SELECT A,
CASE 
  WHEN  **Condition**
  THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by (case when **Condition** then 1 else 0 end) Order by [A] ASC)
END
AS 'DENSE_R'
FROM CTE
```

Comment: I think you need an extra set of `(` `)` around the case.

Comment: No. Just checked. They are not needed.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `case` like this:

```
select A,
       (case when A is not null
             then dense_rank() over (partition by (case when A is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                                     order by a desc
                                    )
        end) as dr
from A1;
```

Comment: When A is null, what happens to the data returned?

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt not post the question correctly, please go back and take a look at the edits. A is never null, 'Its the Dense_R that is causing the issue

Comment: @RossBush Nothing. `dr` will be `null` because there no `else` mentioned.

Comment: @kage77 `partition by` from this query will solve your problem

Comment: @GriGrim Can you please elaborate? Partition over what?

Comment: Thanks @Hogan, but if you see the edits I made 'A' is never null, its the null in 'DENSE_R' thats causing the issue.

Comment: @Hogan its a NULL because of the 'when' condition in the case statement

Comment: @kage77 - oh!  I understand now.  See GriGrim's answer.  You just use the same condition.